# How to control my Win32 service meaning change it's custom parameters, scheduling etc?

Tags: delphi, windows-services, delphi-xe

I need to develop a Win32 service in Delphi XE and I need to find a way how to control it from the same machine (or eventually other machines in the LAN if possible). By controlling it I mean changing it's internal parameters implemented by me, not Windows service parameters. The service itself should not interact with the desktop. Could you please advise the best way how to do it?

Comment: Since Vista, a Win32 service is not able to interact with the Desktop any more, in all cases. Named pipes are a good candidate here.

Comment: Named pipes over a network is a world of hurt. Avoid. For local connectivity only, named pipes are great though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize that this is pretty low tech, but you could actually just keep all the settings in the registry, and then the front-end GUI could write to them, and then the service could periodically check a single key called `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\YourStuff\ConfigurationChangeCounter` and if that value is different, re-read the configuration and apply it (perhaps restarting if necessary).

If you really need to do things other than configuration, then perhaps a TCP socket is lots better, but it's also lots of work to write yourself a custom TCP based protocol handler component and debug that.

But think about it; Your service needs to persist and read configuration anyways, why not just  have it use the code it already has to accomplish this task.  You can remotely connect to a machine and modify its registry values using standard windows tools, and in large corporate networks, such practices are already standard.  Some service elements in Windows itself use this approach.

Comment: You will have to manage the user permissions if you use the registry, but this mechanism can work well. Even a plain INI file will work, in a suitable place. I have a server that simply checks the last update time of an INI file, and if it has changed, it re-reads the parameters. It is a simple solution, for simple needs.

Comment: The ini (or other text configuration) file is the standard approach on Unix-like operating systems and has the benefit of allowing for easier backup, easier initial deployment of new systems, etc. As I don't like the registry much, and am a Unix-guy at heart, this appeals to me, but I know that some people think the opposite way. Remotely writing to a file on disk might be harder than remotely accessing a registry, unless you set up suitable file shares, though, so I suggested Registry instead of file.

Comment: I'm curious, which Microsoft-implemented services use such technique. Citation needed!

Comment: The implementations are closed-source, however, for a starter, look at this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup`

Answer (score 6):

You could use an IPC method like named pipes to communicate with the service or communicate with the service using a TCP socket.

I did it with Named pipes and it works like a charm.

Comment: +1 Named pipes works fine locally - more difficult to work over a Network, due to Windows security enhancements since Vista/Seven. But for a local access, it is better for TCP socket: faster and lighter. My advice is not to be stuck into one communication layer - you may want to change into HTTP later (for remote settings) - this is what we use in [mORMot](http://mormot.net): you can choose between direct call, GDI messages, named pipes or TCP/HTTP for your communication layer. We use named pipe for service remote access, with success. Source code included (Delphi 6 up to XE2).

Comment: There are various tools for this sort of thing. I use RemObjects SDK for when I need a complex interaction, and don't want to bother with how it actually talks "on the wire".

Answer (score 1):

Intraweb server?  Nice, quick, (almost trivial), way to build a web GUI to control a service. Obviously, 'other machines in the LAN', (or even the net), then becomes a matter of routing/security, not feasibility.